# Use structs , maps or something else?

Tags: go

I am new to Go ( and programming to an extent), so using a learn as you practice approach.

For the code below ( which pulls weather forecast ), I am looking to populate the longitude and latitude from a list I have.

I am not entirely sure how to setup that list in the first place - use structs and then pipe the value of the stored struct into this code? I tried that and it seems I can only hold one lon/lat pair in a struct. I was thinking of using maps but couldn't figure out how to set it all up. Perhaps, I should store the list of values in a text file and read from there:

```
p := Place{
    placeName: "Accra", lat: "43.6595", long: "-79.3433",
    placeName: "Kumasi", lat: "43.6595", long: "-79.3433",
    placeName: "Tamale", lat: "43.6595", long: "-79.3433",
}

f, err := forecast.Get(key, p.lat, p.long, "now", forecast.CA)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

the struct looked like this ( I have about 10 separate long/lat values to use)

```
type Place struct {
    placeName string
    lat       string
    long      string
}
```

Comment: [A Tour of Go](http://tour.golang.org/) is probably a much better way to "learn as you practice". What you have here seems sort of random, and it's hard to see what your misunderstanding are.

Comment: @JimB  I am working my way through the tour.  Here, I am simply looking to use multiple values of longitude and latitude for the forecast.Get function above. i can currently use just one.

Comment: If there was more than one value of `p.lat` and `p.long`, how would you access them? The `p` here is a single `Place` value. Do you want a list (slice) of `Place`, a map of strings to lat-long pairs, a map of strings to `Place`?

Comment: I was thinking a map of strings to lat-long pairs

Comment: Have you tried that? Or try using what you have with `map[string]Place`.

Comment: tried it but I think my syntax was wrong - hence asking for help here

Comment: Have you tried the code I provided?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Place` struct is a single object, it has three properties, a name and lat and long. In order to have more than one you have to instantiate them individually, and commonly, you'd store them in a collection. In Go, the sensible choices would be an array, slice, or map.

Here is an example using a slice. The syntax for array is roughly the same. If you'd like I can provide an example that uses a map after I return from lunch. One other thing to note is that I'm allocating the collection using a syntax referred to as 'composite literal' there are other ways to do this... I could use the `append` method or more conventional assignment to indexes/keys like `myArray[0] = instanceOfPlaceThatIsAlreadyInitialized`.

```
places := []Place{
        Place{placeName: "Accra", lat: "43.6595", long: "-79.3433"},
        Place{placeName: "Kumasi", lat: "43.6595", long: "-79.3433"},
        Place{placeName: "Tamale", lat: "43.6595", long: "-79.3433"},
    }
```

Extended example; https://play.golang.org/p/EHBgn_I9dA

EDIT: Same thing with a map;

```
places := map[string]Place{
        "Accra":Place{placeName: "Accra", lat: "43.6595", long: "-79.3433"},
        "Kumasi":Place{placeName: "Kumasi", lat: "43.6595", long: "-79.3433"},
        "Tamale": Place{placeName: "Tamale", lat: "43.6595", long: "-79.3433"},
    }
```

https://play.golang.org/p/1A45-Z6k7q

Comment: this is great! thank you. certainly a learning experience. Will be great to throw any other examples my way - like using maps. much appreciated.

Comment: works great. advice for a newbie - what is the most efficient way to do this?  The long and lat is being used to pull data from a weather api - the idea is to setup the Go code so it cycles through a list of given long/lat values like we have done.  Step 2 for me will be to decide ( and learn ) if its more efficient to pull the data from the api into a mongodb, then pull the data to the front end from there. One step at a time!

Comment: @user2022284 I doubt that it will make much of a difference. In either case, the difference of map vs slice vs array will be very small in comparison to other factors like the time it takes the response to arrive from the third party API or the time it takes to deserialize it and do operations on the data. Generally speaking, arrays offer the best performance, but they're also the most constrained. If you for example know how many entries there will be in the list and you don't care about their order then an array will likely be the fastest structure. Hope that helps.